# How to dynamically get satisfy autocomplete value using .attr() or .on('click', from same source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

I have two input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="text" name="file" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $('input[name=\'image\'], input[name=\'file\']').autocomplete({ 
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var thisType = $(this).attr('name');
        $.getJSON( "files/", {
            term: extractLast( request.term ),
            type: thisType
        }, response );
    },
    create: function () {
        var thisType = $(this).attr('name');
        if (thisType == 'image') {
            $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
     .append('<a><img src="files/' + item.label + '.jpg" />' + item.label + '</a>')
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
        } else {
            $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append('<a>' + item.label + '</a>')
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
        }
    },
    });
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
    if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit;

    $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

    $type = strtolower($_GET["type"]);

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);

    $files = array();

    if ($type == 'image') {
        foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
            $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
        }
    } else {
        foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
            $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
        }
    }

    $files = array_unique($files);
    $files = array_combine($files, $files);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($files as $key=>$value) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
   array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
        }
        if (count($result) > 11) break;
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
```

I want when i type on the first input, as results it need to show me image files name with preview and when type on the second input, as results it need to show me only text files name.Is there any way to if click on or when type or using attr dynamically get satisfy value for each input from same source? I am trying to do link this but not working..

Comment: What are the actual results of your clicks when you console log? If you're back-end logic is ok, could you mimic the response for the front-end in jsfiddler or some site?

Comment: Nothing show in autocomplete result and nothing show error in console log but when i change `$type = strtolower($_GET["type"]);` to `$type = isset($_GET["type"]);` then as results it show me only .txt files name. any solution? @BillPope

Comment: To simplify things, make sure your front-end code is working, first by mimicing the response you're looking for and testing it. Once you rule out that it's not the front-end, you can work on your back-end.

Comment: It working but it show me same results/value for two input. is there any way to get satisfy value using id for this?